# Display all details of XML document for Android app

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating an Android app and want to show all the individual details in an XML document.  So far I can only display the last one in the list.  The following is part of the XML I'm using:

```
<Northwest>
<cp name="PARNELL" spaces="194"></cp>
<cp name="ILAC" spaces="875"></cp>
<cp name="JERVIS" spaces="901"></cp>
<cp name="ARNOTTS" spaces="265"></cp>
</Northwest>
```

I want to display the name and spaces as labels in the app.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the XML file?

Comment: Google has a pretty good write up on parsing XML.  Try giving this a read.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: to be honest i'm new to android development and followed a tutorial to get what i have so far and not going to lie it's fairly confusing so i'm not 100% sure what i've done it's also been a while since i've looked at this code